# Retrieving nodes tagged by multiple terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, services

Let's say I have an articles content type, and a field_tags reference field (with multiple values referencing a "tag" vocabulary)

To retrieve articles referencing, say, "tag1" or "tag2", I do this:

```
jsonapi/node/article?
&filter[tags][condition][path]=field_tags.id
&filter[tags][condition][operator]=IN
&filter[tags][condition][value][]=id-of-tag1
&filter[tags][condition][value][]=id-of-tag2
```

That gives me all articles that have either tag1 or tag2.

However, How can I get all articles that have both tag1 **and** tag2?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried as follow

/jsonapi/node/article?filter[field_tags.meta.drupal_internal__target_id]=5&filter[field_tags.meta.drupal_internal__target_id]=6

[image]

you can see in the screen shot only 1 node filtered which has both 5 & 6 term id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I try this it only returns nodes that have the last value in the filter. So, in your example I think this would only return nodes which have the term id of 6 . In your test, did you have nodes that had only the term id 6? I think they will be returned with that query.

Comment: Yes you are right when i added node only with term id 6 that is also filtered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition grouping and have like below :

```
?filter[tag-group][group][conjunction]=AND

&filter[tagA-filter][condition][path]=field.tags.id
&filter[tagA-filter][condition][value]=id-of-tag1
&filter[tagA-filter][condition][memberOf]=tag-group

&filter[tagB-filter][condition][path]=field.tags.id
&filter[tagB-filter][condition][value]=id-of-tag2
&filter[tagB-filter][condition][memberOf]=tag-group
```

I have not tried that but I think you can even use a code like this:

```
?filter[tagA-filter][condition][path]=field.tags.id
&filter[tagA-filter][condition][value]=id-of-tag1
&filter[tagB-filter][condition][path]=field.tags.id
&filter[tagB-filter][condition][value]=id-of-tag2
```

just notice that in this case two different key is used for conditions

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. When I try it doesn't return any result.